# Tkinter/Python: list1 updates even when it shouldn't when I only compare list2 to list1

Tags: python, list, tkinter, reference

I'm confused as to why an index in the masterList is updated/changed when I don't update/touch it within my code under the updateCustomerList function. I only use it as a reference to my customerList. It only does this when i use a negative quantity value to basically delete or remove objects from the frame

refreshMasterList() just allows me to refresh the frame so the frame will be populated by the new data updated inside the customerList.

NOTE: If the indentation seems wrong, let me know. Also i created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/apsdr3/cc59a13b8890c1342605a77536c56d96) to see the whole program

If you want to run the program and check it out for yourself, just download this [test excel doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i8aHpOPMPIngRov8VVcHqindJSJr19UsEOtw7epGnGw/edit?usp=sharing) and use **3605520297939** as the bar code

```
def updateCustomerList(barCode, quantity):
    global customerList

    if not barCode.get():
        return  
    else:

        for i in range(len(masterList)):

            if int(barCode.get()) == masterList[i][4]:

                if len(customerList) == 0:
                    customerList.append(masterList[i])
                    customerList[0].append(quantity.get())

                    print("Customer list is empty, before delete " + str(customerList) + "         M " + str(masterList[i]))

                    if customerList[0][5] <= 0:
                        del customerList
                        customerList = []

                    print("Customer list is empty" + str(customerList) + "   M " + str(masterList[i]))

                    refreshMainFrame()

                else:

                    print("~CustomerList is not empty " + str(masterList[i]))

                    for j in range(len(customerList)):
                        if int(barCode.get()) == customerList[j][4]:
                            intQuantity = customerList[j][5] + quantity.get()

                            if intQuantity <= 0:
                                del customerList[j]

                            print("~~Customer list is not empty but w/ repeated bar code" + str(customerList) + "   M " + str(masterList[i]))

                            refreshMainFrame()
                            return

                    customerList.append(masterList[i])  #adds a masterList object inside customerList
                    customerList[len(customerList)-1].append(quantity.get())   

                    if customerList[len(customerList)-1][5] <= 0:
                        del customerList[len(customerList)-1]

                    print("~~~Customer list is not empty" + str(customerList) + "   " + str(masterList[i]))

                    refreshMainFrame()

    refreshMainFrame()
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying `masterList` mutable items from inside `customerList`:

```
customerList.append(masterList[i])
customerList[0].append(quantity.get())   #<-- for instance here
```

---

```
customerList.append(masterList[i])
customerList[len(customerList)-1].append(quantity.get()) #<-- and here too
```

Because `customerList` only holds a reference to the modified item, the alterations are visible in both places.

You could try to do a hard copy of every item extracted from `masterList` before manipulating them:

```
customerList.append(masterList[i][:])    #<-- for instance do a hard copy here
customerList[0].append(quantity.get())
```

Comment: Made the changes and it works! I guess I have to read up on lists some more. Thank you!